# Sphinx Qt ValueError: API 'QDate' has already been set to version 1

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, python-sphinx

I am trying to use python's Sphinx module to build a documentation for a Qgis (pyqt) plugin (using Pyqt). 
When trying to build with`make html`, 
I get several exceptions for some modules all being :

```
ValueError: API 'QDate' has already been set to version 1
```

Here is the full stack

```
home/user/path/project.rst:105: WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module u'new_project_base'; the following exception was raised:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sphinx/ext/autodoc.py", line 551, in import_object
    __import__(self.modname)
  File "/home/rescue/bathydeconfliction/new_project_base.py", line 14, in <module>
    from qgis.core import QgsProject
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtCore.py", line 28, in <module>
    sip.setapi(api, 2)
ValueError: API 'QDate' has already been set to version 1
```

What am I doing wrong? (Using python 2.7, sphinx 1.5.2 on Debian Jessie)

Answer (score 4):

importing qgis.core before importing PyQt4 has fixed it for me

```
import  qgis.core 
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
```

qgis isn't part of pyqt but the error occurs when you try to use qgis APIs along with PyQt in the same code. I believe, the reason is qgis defines `QDate` which conflicts with `QDate` in PyQt4

Comment: What is qgis? It doesn't seem a part of pyqt.

Comment: That may be your case, but I don't have qgis and am getting the same error. I suspect the reason being some (>1) packages that use Qt are setting conflicting qt api version.

Comment: worked for me. For my case it was pyuic4 that was having an error. I had to modify the pyuic4 script in /usr/bin/pyuic4 based on this solution http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/qgis-developer/2017-May/048433.html

Comment: Worked for me. I've added in /usr/bin/pyuic4 the line 'import qgis.core' above import 'PyQt4.uic.pyuic'